# $ \mathscr{F}\Big\{e^{-(a-jb) t^2}\Big\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

By using the definition of continuous-time-Fourier-transform:
$$ \mathscr{F}\Big\{x(t)\Big\} \triangleq X(ω) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\, e^{-j 2 \pi ω t} \,\mathrm{d}t$$

and solving the differential equation I ended up with after derivation of the Fourier equation :$${X'(ω)}=\frac{-ω}{2(a-jb)} \cdot X(ω)$$
I calculated

$$X(ω)=\mathscr{F} \Big\{x(t)=\exp(-(a-jb)t^2)\Big\}= K \cdot \exp\left ( \frac{-ω^2}{4(a-jb)}\right) $$

Which is the value of this constant K?

Comment: How did you manage to get that without finding $K$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I edited the post and made it more clear now

Comment: I think what frog meant is that your calculation, if correct, should imply the value of $K$.  So, can you show your calculation?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The final calculation comes direct from the differential equation after writing it with X(ω) on one side only and integrating both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\zeta = a - i b$. To see how the transform is related to the Gaussian integral, make the substitution $t = z/\sqrt \zeta - \pi i \hspace{1px} \omega/\zeta$:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-\zeta t^2 - 2 \pi i \omega t} dt =
\frac {e^{-(\pi \omega)^2/\zeta}} {\sqrt \zeta} \int_\gamma e^{-z^2} dz.$$
Then prove that the integral over the line $\gamma$ is the same as the integral over the real line, with the principal value of the square root giving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2} dz$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
X(0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)\,dt,
$$
so if you can do this integral you should be able to find $K$.

Comment: I think I have to use the well-known integral:$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $$ But which substitution do i have to use since a-jb is a complex number?